# OBJ C button disappears after clicking

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a problem with the button, it's weird but it disappears.

I click on it and it brings me to an other view and then i click back and i am back in my **Mainview** but without button.

I've added this button in *storyboard* - not progamatically.

Comment: Have you set up the button's constrains using autolayout ?

Comment: Confucious says: Is a question on SO without code, actually a question?

Comment: Really hard to say what is going on here. What is your setup, what is the code executed when button is tapped? Give us more information about the issue.

Comment: Yes, i have used autolayout

Comment: It's button made in storyboard, loaded with image, its action is push to other ViewController

Answer (score 0):

Time to start [debugging](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html): Start by putting a breakpoint on `viewDidAppear:` and in the console type:

`po self.whateverYourButtonIsCalled`

Check frame, isHidden, the superview's subviews, transforms, etc.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, where is the place to type in console ?

Comment: In the console at the bottom of your window. I added a picture.

Comment: I'm trying and trying but i cannot type it anywhere.

Comment: You need to setup a breakpoint. http://jeffreysambells.com/2014/01/14/using-breakpoints-in-xcode

Comment: But it's weird because firstly i have this button, i disappears after loading other viewController.